# Golang: Parsing benchmarking between message pack and JSON

Tags: json, go, messagepack

We are working on a TCP server which takes simple textbased commands over TCP (similar to redis)

We are tossing up between using raw text command, JSON or message pack (http://msgpack.org/)

An example of a command could be:

text command: `LOCK some_random_key 1000`

JSON command: `{"command":"LOCK","key":"some_random_key","timeout":1000}`

messagePack: `\x83\xA7command\xA4LOCK\xA3key\xAFsome_random_key\xA7timeout\xCD\x03\xE8`

**Question:**

EDIT: I have figured out my own question which is the speed comparison between parsing JSON and MsgPack. Please see results in my answer

Comment: Your question doesn't say what is more important, data stream size or readability, whether you are encrypting (SSL or anything else) the data stream (they usually compress the data before encrypt), etc. I would suggest to think of the "users" and less of the "server", remember if some ever needs to read your JSON data, he needs it to be readable, if its machines talking to machines, compress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing Speed Comparison:

```
BenchmarkJSON     100000         17888 ns/op
BenchmarkMsgPack      200000         10432 ns/op
```

My benchmarking code:

```
package benchmark

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack"
    "testing"
)

var in = map[string]interface{}{"c": "LOCK", "k": "31uEbMgunupShBVTewXjtqbBv5MndwfXhb", "T/O": 1000, "max": 200}

func BenchmarkJSON(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        jsonB := EncodeJSON(in)
        DecodeJSON(jsonB)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMsgPack(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        b := EncodeMsgPack(in)
        DecodeMsgPack(b)
    }
}

func EncodeMsgPack(message map[string]interface{}) []byte {
    b, _ := msgpack.Marshal(message)
    return b
}

func DecodeMsgPack(b []byte) (out map[string]interface{}) {
    _ = msgpack.Unmarshal(b, &out)
    return
}

func EncodeJSON(message map[string]interface{}) []byte {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(message)
    return b
}

func DecodeJSON(b []byte) (out map[string]interface{}) {
    _ = json.Unmarshal(b, &out)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do some benchmarks on the kind of data that the machines will be talking to each other.

I would suggest to try [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/) (Encoding) + [Snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy-go/) (compression)

Answer (score 1):

msgpack only promises to be shorter than json, not faster to parse. In both cases, your test string is so short and simple that your benchmarking may simply be testing the maturity of the particular implementation, rather than the underlying algorithms.

If all your messages really are this short, parsing speed may be the least of your problems. I'd suggest designing your server such that the parsing bits are easily replaceable and actually profiling the code in action.

Donald Knuth made the following statement on optimization:

"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Lastly if you really want to know what is going on, you need to profile the code. See

http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

for an example of how to profile code with go.

Answer (score 0):

Also, your test cases are reversed
BenchmarkJSON actually calls MsgPack
and 
BenchmarkMsgPack calls Json

could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Yep! You are right. Thanks for noticing it. I have reversed it and posted it as the answer